# Subscribing Multiple FCM Subscriptions At Once?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, web-push

I am implementing push notifications using vapid directly and not through the fcm javascript library. I'd like to register these tokens with fcm, and have been using the same endpoint as the library to do this-

`https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/connect/subscribe`

The problem with this is that it's relatively slow, and becomes and issue when I need to register hundreds of thousands of tokens with fcm in a given time.

Is there a bulk-subscribe endpoint I could be using?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [batchAdd](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#manage_relationship_maps_for_multiple_app_instances) (emphasis mine):

> **Manage relationship maps for multiple app instances**
>
> Using the Instance ID service's batch methods, you can perform batch management of app instances. For example, **you can perform bulk addition or removal of app instances to an FCM or GCM topic**. To update up to 1000 app instances per API call, call the Instance ID service at this endpoint, providing the app instance tokens in the JSON body:
>
> > https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:batchAdd
> >
> > https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:batchRemove